# Powershell script taking only the first value from the variable while running the validation script of Azure webjobs

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-devops, azure-webjobs

I am running the below script to check for the validation of continuous webjobs.As part of my deployment process,I am stopping the webjobs and uploading the jar files and then starting the webjobs.After starting the webjobs.I need to validate whether all the Continuous webjobs properly started or not.If not running, it should fail my VSTS powershell task and display the which continuous webjob is not running.

So In The below script **$status** variable is just taking the status of first continuous webjob and going into the loop and displaying all the webjobs are running but even after starting all the continuous webjobs ,some of the webjobs are not properly started and in that case my script should not say all the webjobs are running.It should fail the task and display the which particular webjobs is not running.

Could any one kindly help me out on this.
Please help me with changing of my script if needed as I am new to powershell.So that the $status variable should check all the status of continuous webjobs then only go into the loop and execute the script and print the webjobs are running.

FYI, I am running the powershell script through VSTS and connecting to Azure.

Powershell Script:

```
$ResourceGroupName=""
$AppService=""
$Apiversion=""
##ContinuousWebJobs
$continuejob=Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName $AppService -ResourceType Microsoft.web/sites/ContinuousWebJobs -ApiVersion $Apiversion 
$status=$continuejob.Properties.status
#$status='Running'
$j=1
while($j -le 5)
{
     if($status -ne 'Running')
     {
        $continuejob=Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName $AppService -ResourceType Microsoft.web/sites/ContinuousWebJobs -ApiVersion $Apiversion 
        $status=$continuejob.Properties.status
        $j+=1 
        "waiting for running, will sleep 6s..."
        sleep 6
     }else{
        Write-Host "already running, exit this script" -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor Green
        sleep 6 
        quit
     }
}
Write-Host  "Error:waiting for 30s already, The job is not running" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Red
```

Comment: Please, can you edit your text as it looks like a big block of characters? That's hardly readable.

Comment: Now, I just segregated my text.Please let me know if you need any other changes or it needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this code:

```
    $ResourceGroupName="XXX"
        $AppService="XXXX"
        $Apiversion="2016-08-01"
        $errorsJobs=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
        $continuejobs=Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName $AppService -ResourceType Microsoft.web/sites/ContinuousWebJobs -ApiVersion $Apiversion 
        foreach($webJob in $continuejobs){
Write-Host $webJob
        $status=$webJob.Properties.status
        if($status -ne "Running"){
          $errorsJobs.Add($webJob.Properties.name)
        }}
      if($errorsJobs.Count -gt 0){
    $result=$errorsJobs -join ";"
    Write-Error $result
    }
```

Comment: Thanks MSFT, Is it possible to display which particular webjob is not running and running in the log ? So that I will get to know Because of the partcular webjob My deployment is failed.Please help here.

Comment: And can you explain what is errorjobs variable is holding,what is the meaning of this line $errorsJobs.Add($webJob.Properties.name) ..Please explain me and please add the script that I requested in the previous comment.

Comment: @PRAVEEN the `$errorsJobs` is the array that contains all web jobs that is not running, and output to the error with these web jobs by using write-error $result. The code of `$errorsJobs.Add($webJob.Properties.name)` is used to add the web job name (status is not Running) to $errorsJobs array.

Comment: You can output the current web job through Write-Host, for example: `foreach($webJob in $continuejobs){ Write-Host $webJob
$status=$webJob.Properties.status ......`, then you can check the build log, it won't displayed in build summary, the message of Write-Error will be displayed in build summary.

Comment: Another issue is like,if my webjobs are running,why this script is failing ? if my webjobs are running this script should nor fail.If any one webjob is not running then only it should fail and display which web jobs is not running.Please do the needful.

Comment: @PRAVEEN Just need to check the items of $errorsJobs array. Updated the code.

Comment: @MSFT, As per your script,it is succeeding the step, even after webjobs are not running,.But it should fail right.

Comment: Add Write-Host $webJob (Updated code), then queue build and share the detail log on the OneDrive.

Comment: I want the script,whenever if any job is not running,it should fail my vsts task and print,the which  webjob name is not running.

Comment: Yes, that script should do it. I need to check the log to analysis the reason.

Comment: @MSFT, I have bit modified the script and ran the script.Now,Its working well.I will let you know if I face any issues.Thank you so much.

Comment: @MSFT, Can I have the validation script after stopping the webjobs ,I need to check whether all are properly stopped or not.Please share the script.

Comment: Just replace running to stopped and check the result. You may open a new thread to discuss this issue if still have the issue.

Comment: @MSFT, I tried giving the same but its throwing error.As you said,errorjobs will be having only not running jobs right.So I thought we may need to find the script for the not stopped jobs.Please help me on that.

Comment: Errorjobs array will be having only not running jobs or not stooped jobs as well ?

Comment: No, if you just replace `Running` to `Stopped`, it contains all not stopped jobs.